# mean is not definedin .agg PYTHON

Tags: python, debugging, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

```
data_bis = data.groupby(['Date']).agg({ 
    'Success Percentage' : mean
})
```

NameError: name 'mean' is not defined

do you know what is problem ? replacing mean by sum works. Why?

Comment: mean like the average of a column

Comment: Use `'mean'` instead of `mean`

Comment: why is it working while for sum I just have to write sum

Comment: `sum` is a `python` keyword so it is understood as is, while `mean` is not, but `'mean'` is a string recognized by the `agg()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), value should be a callable or a sting that pandas can interpret.

> Accepted combinations are:
>
> - string function name.
> - function.
> - list of functions.
> - dict of columnnames -> functions (or list of functions).

```py
data_bis = data.groupby(['Date']).agg({ 
    'Success Percentage' : np.mean
})
```

Or as a string.

```py
data_bis = data.groupby(['Date']).agg({ 
    'Success Percentage' : 'mean'
})
```